# Bootstrap nav collapsing into body of site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I am having issues with my navigation collapsing into the body of my site and I would prefer it to remain fixed when the browser window is re-sized.  I have tried adjusting the min/max-widths of the bootstrapresponsive.css but it still seems to disappear into the body.  Any help would be amazing.  Cheers!  I have posted the code below:

```
<div class="navbar" style="padding-bottom:0px;">
  <div class="navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container" style="width: auto;">
      <div id="logo"><a href="index.php"><img src="images/CoHlogo.jpg" class="logoImage";></a></div>
      <div class="nav-right"> 
        <!--Social Networking-->
        <a class="socialNav" href="mailto:info@classroomofhope.org?subject=Website Inquiry"><img src="img/social/mail.png"/></a>
        <a class="socialNav" href="http://www.youtube.com/user/Classroomofhope" target="_blank"><img src="img/social/youtube.png"/></a>
        <!-- Twitter
        <a class="socialNav" href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="img/social/twitter.png"/></a> -->
        <a class="socialNav" href="https://facebook.com/ClassroomOfHope" target="_blank"><img src="img/social/facebook.png"/></a>
        <!--Google plus
        <a class="socialNav" href="https://google.com" target="_blank"><img src="img/social/googleplus.png"/></a> -->
        <!--Donate Button -->
        <a href="donate.php"><img src="img/donate_header.png" class="donateImage";></a> 
      </div>

      <div class="nav-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav" id="nav">
          <li class="dropdown" id="about"><a href="about_us.php"  class="dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown">ABOUT US</a>


                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li id="values"><a href="our_values.php">OUR VALUES</a></li>
                <li id="journey"><a href="our_journey.php">OUR JOURNEY SO FAR</a></li>
                <li id="founder"><a href="meet_the_founder.php">MEET THE FOUNDER</a></li>
                </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="education"><a href="why_education.php">WHY EDUCATION?</a></li>
          <li id="projects"><a href="projects.php">PROJECTS</a></li>
          <!--<li id="media"><a href="media_centre.php">MEDIA CENTER</a></li>-->
          <li id="donate"><a href="donate.php">DONATE</a></li>
          <li id="contact"><a href="contact_us.php">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removal of the class `.nav-collapse` from one of the `<div>` elements solves this problem. As the name of the class suggests, an element with this class will become hidden on smaller screen sizes (I think below widths of 979px is what the stylesheet says?), by receiving `height:0` and `overflow:hidden` via media query.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2gew/1/) (with externally-loaded Bootstrap CSS) that demonstrates how layout would appear without this class. Try resizing the Result pane to see how it would look at different screen sizes.

I hope this is what you were looking for! If not, let me know and I'll be happy to help further.

(Edit:) On taking a look at your live environment, I can now see that when you say "collapse", you mean the navigation links break to a new line as the parent element becomes too small. This is standard behaviour for floated elements. To stop this from happening, you can try applying `min-width:1200px` or something to that effect to the `.container` element (inside of `.navbar-fixed-top`). Hope this helps!

Comment: THanks so much for the response.  I have removed the <div> but still get the collapse that I don't want for some reason.  The test url is: http://frodlhag.com/CoH/Web for a closer look at what is taking place.  I am struggling with keeping that center navigation <div> position as the social nav icons and "donate" button adjust.  I want them to meet the center nav and remain at the edge of "contact us" opposed to collapsing them as they do??

Comment: Hi, I've edited my response to better address the issue now that I've seen the live environment, try it out and see if it works for you.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant!  Thank you so much for the effort.  Seems so simple when someone else has a look at it.  Cheers man!

Comment: Great! I'm glad this helped you out. Oh, and ah...if this was indeed the correct answer, could you accept it? Thanks!